# DMG Equivalent on Windows

Tags: mac, windows, dmg, iso

I have a folder to distribute. On Mac, I can put all the folder's contents into a DMG, which the user can just click to open and see all the contents.

What is the equivalent on Windows? Some have said ISO, but when I create one, Windows either sees it as a DVD image and opens *Windows Disk Image Burner* or sees it as a compressed directory, making the user extract all contained files before they can be used.

Isn't there something that can just be opened in the same way as a DMG?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot just distribute it as a .zip archive file?

Comment: I'm distributing an application update and would just prefer the users don't have to add any extra steps or have 3rd party software involved. They're not the most tech-savvy bunch.

Comment: You do not need to be tech-savvy to double-click a .zip archive file however if you're distributing an application update for a Windows program, then just distribute it in a proper Windows Installer Executable as a single .exe/.msi file.

Comment: Having to extract the files though—I know they're going to get confused. The program isn't a typical Windows one. It's housed on an external drive. The update though consists of an exe and a resource folder, which the exe uses. Would an installer be able to wrap the two of them and just run the exe?

Comment: Yes, there are single executable self-contained Windows Installers however this whole subject it really off-topic for Ask Different.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Apple software or hardware

Comment: As it is an update I would look at Windows installers - used to be .msi files

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creating a zip file for distribution using Windows.

Right click on the Desktop and select **New->Folder**, as shown below.

[image: 1]

Rename the "New Folder". I used the name "Stuff", as shown below.

[image: 2]

Drag and drop the desired files to this folder. When finished , right click on the folder and select **Send To->Compressed (Zipped) folder**.

[image: 2]

The file "Stuff.zip" will be created, as shown below.

> Note: The .zip file extension may be hidden on your machine.

[image: 4]

You now can distribute the zip file as you would a dmg file. The recipient normally just double clicks on the zip file to open and then can copy files from the opened window.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to go with a zip file. I've tried everything—ISO, IMG, VHD….nothing has the ease of use of a DMG.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 7 & earlier, software is available to mount ISOs as though they were mounted CD/DVDs, but it requires the user to already be prepared for this.
I've previously used [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm) quite successfully.

This has changed with Windows 10 - you can now either Mount or Burn an ISO

From [Addictive Tips : How To Natively Mount And Burn ISO Images In Windows 10](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-natively-mount-and-burn-iso-images-in-windows-10/)

> To mount a disc image, select the file in Windows Explorer and go to the Manage tab. The Manage tab is always context aware and the controls in it change depending on the selected file type. When you select the ISO file, the Manage tab featuring Disc Image Tools has two options; Mount and Burn.
>
> [image]
>
> If you choose to Mount the file, you can see what’s inside and even execute files in it.
>   [image]

Comment: Yeah Windows 10 solves the mounting problem, but most people are still on Windows 7. I'd prefer they don't have to download any third party software.

Comment: ... then it's back to my first draft of this answer... which was essentially "Nope. Aren't Macs wonderful;) You'd be best served just using Zip."

Comment: Macs have spoiled us.